# Define variable through taglib inside body

Tags: java, variables, taglib

I have a taglib below

```
<po:create-option-entry var="optionEntry">

    <li>${optionEntry.name}: <%=HtmlElementUtil.printAction(optionEntry.getAction())%></li>

</po:create-option-entry>
```

and I'm getting the exception that optionEntry is not defined.. I've already seen some code like that but cant remember how it was wired to make the variable visible inside the body of the taglib.

ps.: the taglib's definition follows

```
<tag>  
    <name>create-option-entry</name>
    <tagclass>br.com.facilit.portlets.planooperativo.taglib.action_menu_entry.CreateOptionEntryTag</tagclass>   
    <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>

    <attribute>
        <name>var</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. The tag probably defines a page-scope attribute named "optionEntry", and not a local variable named `optionEntry`.

Comment: but I want to use scriptlets in this case..

Comment: But you shouldn't. Never. Define a custom tag or a custom EL function instead if you need one. Whatever you use, you'll need to access the page-scope attribute named `optionEntry`.

Comment: you being a little rigid.. scriptlets exists to be used and I dont agree when some people say that are pieces of ugly and poor code.. I like scriptlets and they avoid me spend a lot of time..

Comment: scriptlets exist because Sun/Oracle wants to maintain backward compatibility with old applications that were written, 15 years ago, when the EL and custom tags didn't exist yet.

Comment: Why mix scriptlets and EL?  If you're already using EL, might as well use all EL.  And if you want scriptlets, use all scriptlets.  But mixing the two just makes a mess.

Comment: @JBNizet I dont think so.. scriptlets are no good for designers when they get codes from developers to put their art and beauty.. to other developers I believe that scriptlets are a lot more quick and clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to accomplish my question. all I need to do is create a CreateOptionEntryTei

```
<tag>  
    <name>create-option-entry</name>
    <tagclass>pack.CreateOptionEntryTag</tagclass>
    <teiclass>pack.CreateOptionEntryTei</teiclass>
    <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
    <attribute>
        <name>var</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

and define the class like this

```
public class CreateOptionEntryTei extends TagExtraInfo {

    public VariableInfo[] getVariableInfo(TagData data) {

        String var = data.getAttributeString("var");

        return new VariableInfo[] { new VariableInfo(var, OptionEntry.class.getName(), true, VariableInfo.NESTED), };
    }
}
```